# how to access token into the strongloop to ionic framwork

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, strongloop

Hello I am a new user in ionic frame work. 
My question is another user use the stongloop framework for creating/build the apis. they also use the access token into the strongloop.
But problem is how to set the access token into the ionic frame work for fetching the data by api into the strongloop.

How to set the token in ionic frame work.

Please help me i am a new user.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Ionic is a front-end framework for developing native-feeling hybrid mobile apps in HTML5 using Sass and **AngularJS**.

which means that you can use Loopback AngularJS SDK as for web client application.

1. Generate angularjs $resource services using lb-ng command
2. Include generated file in your ionic project

See detailed instructions in [AngularJS SDK docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Setup). The only thing that you will probably have to change is 'urlBase' variable inside generated file. Add URL to your API here, or assign it dynamically (see [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Clientconfiguration) how to do it).

If you setup everything correctly, SDK will take care about tokens when using LoopbackJS models.